# Impose NA values of one data frame on identically formatted second data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, na

I have two data frames, formatted the same,
whereby the NA values in DF1 should be imposed on DF2, leaving all other values in DF2 intact.

Example below, with code to reproduce the two DFs and desired resulting DF underneath:

[image]

```
structure(list(ID = c(100, 101, 102, 103), c1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
"Y"), c2 = c("Y", NA, NA, "Y"), c3 = c("Y", "Y", "Y", NA), c4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA), c5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

structure(list(ID = c(100, 101, 102, 103), c1 = c(0, 0, 0, NA
), c2 = c(1, 0, 0, 0), c3 = c(0, 0, 0, 1), c4 = c(0, 0, NA, 0
), c5 = c(1, 0, NA, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

structure(list(ID = c(100, 101, 102, 103), c1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA), c2 = c(1, NA, NA, 0), c3 = c(0, 0, 0, NA), c4 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA), c5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do an assignment (if the dimensions are the same)

```
DF3 <- DF2
DF3[is.na(DF1)] <- NA
```

-output

```
> DF3
   ID c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
1 100 NA  1  0 NA NA
2 101 NA NA  0 NA NA
3 102 NA NA  0 NA NA
4 103 NA  0 NA NA NA
```

Comment: I often think the answer to something is going to be much more complicated than it turns out to be... Thanks you Akrun